# Sitecore license and development question

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I currently work for a company that bought Sitecore & used a partner, my company bought 1 license.

The site went live a few months ago and now my company have now decided to cut ties with our partner and take the development of the sitecore site and any other sites inhouse.

My question is: Using the license our company currently has, can we develop the site, and can we create new sites etc?

If anyone can shed any light on what can and cant be done would be great as at the moment Im trying to get my head round how we take our current live site forward and how we think about creating new sites inside sitecore also.

Regards
kyllle

Comment: Is there a reason you don't ask the license question to the company Sitecore itself?

Comment: Basically we had a conference call with sitecore last week, they told us on one instance they said that yeah you could possibly develop on 1 license but they recommend the development license whichh costs £17,000 now with out company we are in a tugowar between 2 departments, 1 saying yes to the development server the other saying that we can just develop using subdomains dev.domain and test.domain etc etc At the moment Im trying to get my head round what is the best appoach for everyone and how easy will it be to set up and develop sites using 1 license

Comment: You're entering sort of a gray area. Subdomains will not be your solution, neither license wise or for ease of development. The Sitecore license isn't tied to a "box" per se, it's tied to a solution - subdomains doesn't come in to effect.

Were I you, I would also consider how support is going to work. Sitecore normally offers 1st level support through it's partner channel, not end-customers (as a general rule, I know for a fact this isn't always upheld).

Comment: Ok thanks for that Mark, at the moment Sitecore have provided us with a 2 month developer evaluation license where we can 'play' around with the CMS, we have received the site source off our ex partner and have imported this into out evaluation version, because I have had no exposure to Sitecore Im just trying to clarify how everything is going to work and what is the best approach. Our current site is hosted with company A and we want to move this site to company B next month, whats the best method of doing this?

Comment: Hi Mark, what method of development would you recommend using the 1 server license or is this something you wouldnt recommend at all? At the moment we are trying to work out what the right approach should be and whether or not £17,000 on a development license is something that is of complete value to us. Our plans are to further develop our current sitecore site as well as design and develop an additional 4 individual sites all integrated with Sitecore as well as some microsites? Any advice you have would be great. Thanks

Comment: With regards to moving the site from company A to company B, there shouldn't be an issue, if you get everything move (ie. sitecore file, solution files, databases, license file).

If the solution was developed by another company getting the source code would be a good idea too.

Comment: Where I might see a problem is when the license runs out and you need to get a new one from Sitecore, it's probably not that big of an issue, you just need to have prepared and ordered a new license from Sitecore.

About the Sitecore Dev license, I think it would be easiest for you to have this license (and possibly the only legal way for it).

About the new sites, they might require seperate licenses or you should get a license that covers more sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the license your company uses is a developer license, you can continue using it to develop that site and others, if it is for a different site and not a dev license you'll need to get a developer license from Sitecore.

You can usually email them at support@sitecore.com (it'll take a while to get a reply though).